# Switch on an if statement?

Tags: java, if-statement, switch-statement

I am a bit of a beginner with coding, so can someone please tell me if it is possible to do something like this in Java, in a void result type?

```
switch (if this != null {return this;}
            else {return that;}) {

    case "This": blah
        break;
    case"That": blah
        break;
}
```

Also, can anyone tell me the most efficient way to do a switch statement with two variables? Thanks! :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the [ternary operator](https://alvinalexander.com/java/edu/pj/pj010018):

```
switch (this != null ? this : that) {
    ...
}
```

Or the [Optional](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) class:

```
switch (Optional.ofNullable(this).orElse(that)) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The simple non answer: don't do such a thing. Because such code is hard to read and maintain.

If at all, do something like

```
switch(computeLookupValue(whatever))
```

But your idea to do that many things in a few lines of code is bad practice.

And then also forget that part about efficiency. In Java, you write efficient code by writing simple code that can be optimized by the just in time compiler for you. Trying to write "smart" Java source code can quickly lead to you preventing the JIT from doing its job!

Comment: Ok, thank you, I'll keep this in mind. However for this one though, my actual code has an incredible amount of 'cases,' so it would be more efficient for me to keep the lines of code to a minimum so that it is easy for me to find what I am looking for. (Kind of also why I asked what the most efficient way it is to do this with 2 variables also)

Comment: In that case you are probably using a bad design then. Switch statements are something to be used with great care. We would have to see the problem you actually try to solve by having large switches. One better answer might be to use hashing, and pre computed lookup tables then.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do it directly with an `if` but you can with the ternary operator.

Here is an example:

```
String str = null;
String st = "foo";
switch (str != null ? str : st) {
    case "foo":
        System.out.println(st);
}
```